# Confluent Audit Logs and Confluent Control Center Access Control

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-control-center

Confluent has something called Audit Logs which are written to internal topics (if configured) and which log access to Kafka resources such as clients writing or reading from particular topics. That's all great, however, there are components in a Confluent/Kafka setup such as Confluent Control Center which (should) have a RBAC access set up for users to log in and use.

It is possible to set it up and have users log in with username and password but I am having difficulties in locating where exactly Confluent provides logs of successful/unsuccessful login attempts. If I set the Control Center logs to DEBUG, I can see the HTTP communication and the password lookup for when a user tries to login but I don't see an option for admin review and control of such events. Audit Logs are apparently only for Kafka resources. Is there no other option other than building up a custom solution, scraping DEBUG logs?

Comment: If I understand the question, you want HTTP access logs? Maybe you should front Control Center with Nginx/httpd reverse proxy where you can access that information better?

Answer (score 0):

The list of auditable events is [documented here](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/security/audit-logs/auditable-events.html#management-events). Confluent Control Center login events are unfortunately not one of them.

Comment: Any idea about Connector logs. Although it isn't in the list provided by you but still would like to check if there is any way to enable for connectors.